# Using LINQ to Select a Different Type

Tags: c#

How can I convert my List object to `List<CustomObjects>`

Currently am doing as

```
var db = new DataClasses1DataContext();
var list =
    (from t in db.CTRL_DATA_ERROR_DETAILs
     select new {t.DATA_ERROR_KEY, t.CTRL_DATA_ERROR_MASTER.CREATION_DATE})
        .ToList();

var cus = new List<CustomObjects>();
foreach (var list1 in list)
{
    var cs = new CustomObjects
                 {
                     MasterColumn = list1.DATA_ERROR_KEY.ToString(),
                     ChildColumn = list1.CREATION_DATE.ToString()
                 };
    cus.Add(cs);
}
```

Is there other good way to do this.

Comment: There's no such thing as C#3.5. Also, some hints: please omit "Hello" and "Thanks", since this is a Q&A site, not a discussion forum. I know it is polite to include such things in a conversation, but we're not having a conversation here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to create the CustomObject list in the initial step like so:

```
var db = new DataClasses1DataContext();
var cus =
        (from t in db.CTRL_DATA_ERROR_DETAILs
         select new CustomObjects { MasterColumn = t.DATA_ERROR_KEY.ToString(), 
            ChildColumn = t.CTRL_DATA_ERROR_MASTER.CREATION_DATE.ToString()})
            .ToList();
```

I haven't compiled the code, but the concept should be right.